# Jquery multiple file upload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm using Jquery File Upload plugin, to upload files, here is method which gets files from server and generates HTML and inserts in into an element:

```
 getFilesToHolders:function (id,tablesName) {
            //attachecedFiles is a container for the generated html
            var attachedFiles = $('#IDAttachedfiles');
            // clears this area in case of multiple file upload
            attachedFiles.html('');
            attachments.getFiles(id,tablesName,function(data) {
            // getFiles just does an ajax request
                var template = '<li class="list-group-item"><b>File:</b> <span class="filenameClassAtt"></span> | <b>Extension:</b> <span class="label label-warning extensionAttachedFile"></span> <a href="" class="pull-right attachment-remove-class" style="padding-left:10px; color:#e74c3c;"><i class="fa fa-remove "></i></a>  <a class="pull-right download-attachment-class"  href=""><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></li>';
                if (!data.length) {
                    attachedFiles.html('<h2>No files</h2>');
                    return;
                }
                $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                     var newTemp = $(template);
                     newTemp.find('.filenameClassAtt').html(val.url);
                     newTemp.find('.extensionAttachedFile').html(val.extension);
                     newTemp.find('.download-attachment-class').attr({
                        'id': 'IDAttachmentDownload-'+val.id,
                        'data-tabel-name': val.table_name,
                        'data-record-id' :val.record_id
                     });;
                     newTemp.find('.attachment-remove-class').attr({
                        'id': 'IDAttachmentDelete-'+val.id,
                        'data-tabel-name': val.table_name,
                        'data-record-id' :val.record_id
                     });
                     attachedFiles.append(newTemp);
                });
            });
        },
```

and this is method which executes after a file upload :

```
done: function (e, data) {
            var data = data.result;
            if (data.success == 1) { 
               attachments.getFilesToHolders(data.record_id,data.table_name);
               swal(data.data,false,'success');
            }else{

               app.helper.displayErrors(data);
            }

        },
```

and this method make use of the above method to load the files on the page after upload, so the **problem** here is when I upload multiple files done method executes multiple times and for some reason list of files generated after upload is multiplied by the amount of files I've uploaded even though `getFilesToHolders` method clears the div each time it is called `attachedFiles.html('');` so I don't know why the list is dublicated , here is sceenshot : [image]

here I heve uploaded only 4 files but got 16 on the page, from server side is OK, also when I get files after upload its also works fine shows 4 out of 4

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with asynchronicity, `done` function was firing asynchronously so my getFile function was in the "queue" , the fix was just to place `attachedFiles.html('');` inside getFile function, so it will erase everything and start over, populating the div;